# Spring3 @ExceptionHandler for ServletRequestBindingException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using a Default AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter which I believe should enable support for @ExceptionHandler. Unluckily, a ServletRequestBindingException is thrown if a call to a handler method like this below is coming in - and not Exception handler is invoked.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/products/{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml,application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ProductDemoDTO getProductByCode(@PathVariable final String code,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "BASIC") final String options)
{
    //omitted
}
```

Here teh ExceptionHandler, never called:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
//TODO not being called?
public void handleException(final Exception e, final HttpServletRequest request, final Writer writer) throws IOException
{
    writer.write(String.format("{\"error\":{\"java.class\":\"%s\", \"message\":\"%s\"}}", e.getClass(), e.getMessage()));
}
```

Does anyone know why the ExceptionHandler is not called?

Comment: Damn, it seems if an exception is thrown inside the handler methodm the @ExceptionHandler works. But here the problem seems to be that the exception is thrown by the framework as it detects the incoming call is not sufficient (e.g. based on header, requestmethod or requestmapping). How can I catch these exceptions and handle them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot handle it with spring custom implementation.

it may not an elegant solution  but you still can catch it with web.xml `<error-page>` tag. you can catch exception type or error code from here.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed in Spring 3.2. You can create a global exception handler class with the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation. Then in that class add an `@ExceptionHandler` method to handle the ServletRequestBindingException and return a custom response body. Example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleServletRequestBindingException(ServletRequestBindingException ex)   {
      return new ResponseEntity<String>("MISSING REQUIRED HEADER",HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_REQUIRED);
  }
}
```

For more information check the spring mvc docs: [17.11 Handling exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `@ExceptionHandler` methods are only invoked for exceptions that are thrown from *within* the handler method. `ServletRequestBindingException` is an infrastructure exception that is thrown whilst trying to invoke a handler method, and if the handler method itself cannot be invoked for whatever reason, then the `@ExceptionHandler` is not used.

There doesn't really seem to be a nicer way to handle this. Without knowing what's causing your `ServletRequestBindingException`, though, it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Aaand thanks to **Juergen Hoeller** this has been solved today and should appear in **Spring 4.3**.

Please refer to the issue:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11106