# Why exception handler is not catching error in Spring MVC

Tags: spring

I want to catch an Error in springMVC3 using exception handler. I annotated the exception. I can catch throwable and any exception. But when I tried with Error, It is not catching the exception. Any idea why it is so? The below code catches exceptions

```
ExceptionHandler(InvalidDataException.class)
public ModelMap handleException(InvalidDataException ex) {
    logger.debug("exception catched  :" + ex);

    return new ModelMap();

}
```

But the below is not catching;

```
@ExceptionHandler(Error.class)
public ModelMap handleException(Error ex) {
    logger.debug("exception catched  :" + ex);

    return new ModelMap();

}
```

Comment: Which exception do you throw in both cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why error is not getting catched ,if I throw from my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184593/why-error-is-not-getting-catched-if-i-throw-from-my-code)

Comment: This has just been fixed - please refer to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153132/spring3-exceptionhandler-for-servletrequestbindingexception/36334660#answer-36334660

Answer (score 3):

The second example is not working because you are catching an [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), which extends [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) and *not* [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). You will find that the code will work if you change to the '@ExceptionHandler' and the 'handleException()' method to either 'Exception', 'InvalidDataException' or any other *exception* that is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Even I too faced the same problem ,I think @ExceptionHandler can deal with exceptions only not with throwable and errors
Refer the link:[ExceptionHandler doesn't work with Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548508/exceptionhandler-doesnt-work-with-throwable)