# Why error is not getting caught, even when explicitly thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to catch an "Error" in SpringMVC3 using annotated "@ExceptionHandler". I can catch throwable and any exception, but when I tried with "Error" it is not catching the exception. Any idea why? The code below demonstrates the problem.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestExceptionController {

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestExceptionController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processData(int intValue) throws InvalidDataException {

        if (intValue < 6) {
            try {
                throw new Exception();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new InvalidDataException();
            }
        }

        return "test";

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidDataException.class)
    public ModelMap handleException(InvalidDataException ex) {
        logger.debug("exception catched  :" + ex);

        return new ModelMap();

    }
}
```

The above code catches, but below code is not catching. Why is it not catching the error?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestExceptionController {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestExceptionController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processData(int intValue) throws Error{

        if (intValue < 6) {
            try {
                throw new Exception();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw new Error();
            }
        }
        return "test";

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Error.class)
    public ModelMap handleException(Error ex) {
        logger.debug("exception catched  :" + ex);

        return new ModelMap();

    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please edit your existing question rather than creating a new one. I've voted to close the original.

Comment: Which version of Spring3 are you using?

Comment: did this answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184593/why-error-is-not-getting-caught-even-when-explicitly-thrown/8212177#8212177

Answer (score 4):

Actually I looked into the source of spring DispatcherServlet and in line 809 it explains why Error cannot be handled

```
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Object handler = (mappedHandler != null ? mappedHandler.getHandler() : null);
            mv = processHandlerException(processedRequest, response, handler, ex);
            errorView = (mv != null);
        }
```

The code is the part where spring processess the ExceptionResolvers may it be annotation or bean based. You can see that Spring only cathces Exception not Throwable. Error is not a subclass of Exception but throwable so you wont be able to handle it with Spring this way. On a related note the annotation is also called @ExceptionHandler so it kind of implies that it wont work with Errors.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) javadocs:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a
>   "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most
>   applications should not try to catch it.

Catching an Error (or any other Throwable that is not a subclass of Exception) is a bad idea. Spring is doing the right thing by not supporting it.

Comment: I **totally disagree** with the statement `Spring is doing the right thing by not supporting it`. As per mentioned Javadocs, *most applications shouldn't try to catch Errors* but this actually means that **there are reasonable situations when these should be caught**, so Spring simply doesn't support edge-cases. One simple **example of** such **reasonable situation is basic logging** of such exceptions and this is not currently possible using Spring so I see this as an **architectural flaw of Spring**.

Comment: One more example of `Error` that may happen during runtime and should be logged is **UnsatisfiedLinkError** - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html , which **could be detected only at runtime** and **should be aprropriately logged**. This error usually doesn't lead to the crash of the whole JVM, but rather affects part of functionality which uses dynamic library and is perfect example of `Error` that should be caught for logging purposes and `Error` after which web application continue working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I also crashed into this, from the code pasted by @peter-szanto seems there is no possibility to handle java.lang.Error with a Spring-registered handler. My use case would be to handle error with a localized page and also to log the error. My workaround is to use web.xml with error-page/error-code 500 defined and as error-page/location a Spring-handled controller (not a JSP) in order to get localization work. Downside is that when controller code runs there is no authentication for the current user. This catches also things Spring could not possibly handle like a wrong URI not mapped to Spring.

Answer (score -1):

For me the below works with Spring 3.0.5 MVC

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public NotFoundException() {
        super();
    }
}

 @ExceptionHandler
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "employee/{id}",
            headers = "Accept=application/json,application/x-protobuf,application/xml")
    public @ResponseBody method(xxxx)
{
..
throw new NotFoundException
...
}
```

Comment: How is this related to handling `Error`'s (not `Exception`'s)?

Answer (score -2):

didnt meant to handle Exception instead of Error? Error is very ralely used in Java and has a very few implementing classes.

Comment: Assert is a good example of an Error.  We've also seen some class linkage errors in production when we changed a jar without updating the others.

Comment: @Gray I am not saying there is no valid case to handle an Error, all I say is that it is not too common. Additinally the debug message says "exception catched" and the Exception handler method is called handleException. If he would be genuinely interested in Error shouldnt it be rather "error catched" and handleError ?