# ExceptionHandler doesn't work with Throwable

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, web-applications

Ours is a Spring MVC based REST application. I am trying to use ExceptionHandler annotation to handle all errors and exceptions.

I have

```
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public @ResponseBody String handleErrors() {
        return "error";
    }
```

This works whenever there is an exception thrown and it doesn't work for any errors.

I am using Spring 4.0. Is there any work-around?

Comment: Is there any reasonable, good, rational explanation why you would want to handle `Error` as *well* as `Exception` and `RuntimeException`?  Handling `Throwable` just feels... ***wrong*** to me.

Comment: I want to respond with a meaningful json to the front end app and don't want to respond with 500 / stacktrace.

Comment: Sometimes a 500 *is* meaningful - it means that something on the server has gone catastrophically wrong.  Simply saying "error" without context doesn't do any justice on what really happened.

Comment: @Makoto as for the user this doesn't matter - whether something went catastrophically wrong or just wrong - in the end, some functionality is not working, and one should show appropriate error.

Comment: This has just been fixed - please refer to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153132/spring3-exceptionhandler-for-servletrequestbindingexception/36334660#answer-36334660

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to what the `ExceptionHandler#value()` attribute indicates

```
Class<? extends Throwable>[] value() default {};
```

and `@ExceptionHandler` is only meant to handle `Exception` and its sub types.

Spring uses `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` to resolve your annotated handlers, using the following method

```
doResolveHandlerMethodException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception)
```

which as you can see only accepts an `Exception`.

You cannot handle `Throwable` or `Error` types with `@ExceptionHandler` with this configuration.

I would tell you to provide your own `HandlerExceptionResolver`  implementation which does handle `Throwable` instances, but you'd need to provide your own `DispatcherServlet` (and most of the MVC stack) yourself since `DispatcherServlet` does not `catch` `Throwable` instances at any place where you could make any significant difference.

---

Update:

Since 4.3, Spring MVC wraps a thrown `Throwable` value in a `NestedServletException` instance and exposes that to the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: How do i go about this? Is there any design suggestion? How about a Servlet Filter or an interceptor?

Comment: @las `Throwable` and `Error` are much more serious than could be handled by responding to your client. Don't handle them. Just configure and deploy so that they don't happen (as much as possible).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I totally agree but imho that's a serious limitation of Spring. One legitimate case of handling all `Throwable` instances is custom logging of them.

Comment: Also, as per following comment of `Juergen Hoeller` - one of Spring's authors - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13788?focusedCommentId=122373&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-122373 - `even OutOfMemoryError is absolutely recoverable in some cases`, so it makes a lot of sense to catch them.

Comment: I don't know if and/or when this was changed, but this is not correct anymore when using spring boot 3.2.2. You can catch the error just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a kind of Hacking to capture Error in Spring MVC.
First, define an Interceptor like this :

```
public class ErrorHandlingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception
{
    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);

    controller.handleError(ex.getCause(), request, response);
} }
```

Second, define a method in your controller like "handleError" method:

```
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
    errorResponse.setExceptionId(exceptionId);
    errorResponse.setErrorMsg(ex.toString());
    errorResponse.setServerStackTrace(serverStackTrace(ex));

    response.setStatus(responseCode);
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    writer.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), errorResponse);
```

Finally, config your interceptor in Spring configuration.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="ErrorHandlingInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Code in DispatchServlet:

```
            catch (Exception ex) {
            Object handler = (mappedHandler != null ? mappedHandler.getHandler() : null);
// This is where to handle Exception by Spring.
// If Error happens, it will go to catch Error statement 
// which will call afterCompletion method
            mv = processHandlerException(processedRequest, response, handler, ex);
            errorView = (mv != null);
        }

        // Did the handler return a view to render?
        if (mv != null && !mv.wasCleared()) {
            render(mv, processedRequest, response);
            if (errorView) {
                WebUtils.clearErrorRequestAttributes(request);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '" + getServletName() +
                        "': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling");
            }
        }

        // Trigger after-completion for successful outcome.
        triggerAfterCompletion(mappedHandler, interceptorIndex, processedRequest, response, null);
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Trigger after-completion for thrown exception.
        triggerAfterCompletion(mappedHandler, interceptorIndex, processedRequest, response, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Error err) {
        ServletException ex = new NestedServletException("Handler processing failed", err);
        // Trigger after-completion for thrown exception.
        triggerAfterCompletion(mappedHandler, interceptorIndex, processedRequest, response, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
```

Comment: "mv = processHandlerException(processedRequest, response, handler, ex);" is where to handle Exception and only Exception by Spring.
If Error happens, it will go to catch Error statement which will call afterCompletion method which will convert Error to Exception and invoked by your Interceptor