# @ExceptionHandler for Error gets called only if there's no mapping for Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

Using spring-web-4.2.6, I have the following Controller and ExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> HandleDefaultException(Exception ex) {
    ...
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InternalError.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> HandleInternalError(InternalError ex) {
    ...
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myController")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean myAction() {
        throw new InternalError("");
    }
}
```

For some reason, the ExceptionsHandler's HandleDefaultException (for Exception.class) method is invoked, with an exception of type NestedServletException, instead of the HandleInternalError call.

When removing the default call, the IntenalError call is called with the proper InternalError exception.

I do not want to remove the default call as it is important to me to have a default handler to allow for a better experience for my users.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Apparently I'm using spring-web-4.3.3, without asking for it. I don't understand why exactly, here's my Gradle dependencies tree: http://pastebin.com/h6KXSyp2

Comment: Are you sure you're using 4.2.6? The behavior you describe should only work with 4.3+.

Answer (score 7):

Spring MVC should only exhibit the behavior you describe with version 4.3 and above. See [this JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11106). Previously, Spring MVC would not expose any `Throwable` values to `@ExceptionHandler` methods. See

- [ExceptionHandler doesn't work with Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548508/exceptionhandler-doesnt-work-with-throwable)

---

Since 4.3, Spring MVC will catch any `Throwable` thrown from your handler methods and wrap it in a `NestedServletException`, which it will then expose to the normal `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` process.

Here's a short description of how it works:

1. Checks if the handler method's `@Controller` class contains any `@ExceptionHandler` methods.
2. If it does, tries to resolve one that can handle the `Exception` type (including `NestedServletException`). If it can, it uses that (there's some sorting if multiple matches are found). If it can't, and the `Exception` has a [`cause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--), it unwraps and tries again to find a handler for that. That `cause` might now be a `Throwable` (or any of its subtypes).
3. If it doesn't. It gets all the `@ControllerAdvice` classes and tries to find a handler for the `Exception` type (including `NestedServletException`) in those. If it can, it uses that. If it can't, and the `Exception` has a `cause`, it unwraps it and tries again with that `Throwable` type.

In your example, your `MyController` throws an `InternalError`. Since this is not a subclass of `Exception`, Spring MVC wraps it in an `NestedServletException`.

`MyController` doesn't have any `@ExceptionHandler` methods, so Spring MVC skips it. You have a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class, `ExceptionsHandler`, so Spring MVC checks that. The `@ExceptionHandler` annotated `HandleDefaultException` method can handle `Exception`, so Spring MVC chooses it to handle the `NestedServletException`.

If you remove that `HandleDefaultException`, Spring MVC won't find something that can handle `Exception`. It will then attempt to unwrap the `NestedServletException` and check for its `cause`. It'll then find the `HandleInternalError` which can handle that `InternalError`.

This is not an easy issue to deal with. Here are some options:

Create an `@ExceptionHandler` that handles `NestedServletException` and do the check for `InternalError` yourself.

```
@ExceptionHandler(NestedServletException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> HandleNested(NestedServletException ex) {
    Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof InternalError) {
        // deal with it
    } else if (cause instanceof OtherError) {
        // deal in some other way
    }
}
```

This is fine unless there's a bunch of different `Error` or `Throwable` types you want to handle. (Note that you can rethrow these if you can't or don't know how to handle them. Spring MVC will default to some other behavior, likely returning a 500 error code.)

Alternatively, you can take advantage of the fact that Spring MVC first checks the `@Controller` (or `@RestController`) class for `@ExceptionHandler` methods first. Just move the `@ExceptionHandler` method for `InternalError` into the controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myController")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean myAction() {
        throw new InternalError("");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = InternalError.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> HandleInternalError(InternalError ex) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Now Spring will first attempt to find a handler for `NestedServletException` in `MyController`. It won't find any so it will unwrap `NestedServletException` and get an `InternalError`. It will try to find a handler for `InternalError` and find `HandleInternalError`.

This has the disadvantage that if multiple controllers' handler methods throw `InternalError`, you have to add an `@ExceptionHandler` to each. This might also be an advantage. Your handling logic will be closer to the thing that throws the error.

Comment: Apparently I'm using spring-web-4.3.3, without asking for it. I don't understand why exactly, here's my Gradle dependencies tree: http://pastebin.com/h6KXSyp2

Comment: Suppose I am using 4.3.3, can I create two classes with @ControllerAdvice, one for specific exceptions (such as InternalError) and one for the default exception and have the one with the specific exceptions fire first?

Comment: I ended up creating two @ControllerAdvice classes with @Order(1) to the specific exceptions and Order(2) to the general one.