# Spring boot ConstraintViolationException handler is called only if @PreAuthorize annotation is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to implement @PathVariable validation therefore I created a base class for all controllers with exception handler:

```
  public class BaseController {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public RestError handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
            strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage());
            strBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.lastIndexOf("\n"));

        return new RestError(strBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

In controllers that extend BaseController following method signature works as expected (returns {"error": invalid id}):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VISA_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<UserRepresentation> getUser(@Pattern(regexp = Constants.UUID_REGEX, message = "invalid id")
                                           @PathVariable String id
```

Whereas the same method without @PreAuthorize returns status code 500 and message: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.` As if there is no exception handler.

I'm new to spring boot so any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

**Edit**.

Here is the source code of the controller (it actually implements interface that describes the api):

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class UserController extends BaseController implements UserApi {
    private IUserService userService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<UserRepresentation> getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        UserRepresentation userRepresentation = userService.getUserRepresentationById(id);

        if (userRepresentation == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepresentation, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put a full Controller that extends the `BaseController` source code?

Comment: Also see here it has some very useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40346507/3635454

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I believe you're missing the [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation in your controller class.

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated // class level
public class BaseController {
    //...
}
```