# Spring - Manage custom Exception page

Tags: spring

I'm trying to manage a custom error page with my custom exception.
I have this exception

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Inesistente")
public class ResourceNotAccessibleException extends Throwable{

    public ResourceNotAccessibleException(String message){
        super(message);
    }


}
```

which i want to respond with a 404 error.
Than i'm managing an error controller

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

@ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotAccessibleException.class})
    public ModelAndView getErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
        String errorMsg = "";
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(request);


        switch (httpErrorCode) {
        case 404: {

            logger.error("Status Error " + httpErrorCode , ex.getMessage());
            errorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("errorMessage", new Object[] { uuid, +httpErrorCode }, locale);
            break;
        }
        case 400: {
            errorMsg = "BAD REQUEST";
            break;
        }

        case 500: {
            errorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("errorMessage", new Object[] { uuid, +httpErrorCode }, locale);
            logger.error("Status Error " + httpErrorCode , ex.getMessage());
            break;
        }
        }
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);

        mav.setViewName("error");

        return mav;
    }
```

Now, in my controller if i have something like

```
if(object==null) {
throw new ResourceNotAccessibleException("Resource does not exist");
}
```

I should see my error view, but i'm getting the classic white error page, in my log i see the exception being hit..

Answer (score 0):

The `ResourceNotAccessibleException` should extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException` and not `Throwable`. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548572/1032167)

If you can't change exception type, probably you could try `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` or this [awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30193013/1032167) about Spring exception handling

---

One more thing, you probably want to add some @ResponseStatus info above `getErrorPage`, because you are handling this exeption and @ResponseStatus annotation above the `ResourceNotAccessibleException` will never trigger.

So i think something like this should work:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) // <= important
    @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotAccessibleException.class})
    public ModelAndView getErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
        String errorMsg = "";

        // ... some code here

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);

        mav.setViewName("error");

        return mav;
    }
}


public class ResourceNotAccessibleException extends Exception{ // <= important

    public ResourceNotAccessibleException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

---

If this doesn't work, you can also try to change resource view file name to something like `errorPage.jsp` or `errorPage.html` and set it like `mav.setViewName("errorPage");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the **default error pages** in your web container and **map a status code to a particular error page**.

Here are the changes you need to make:

1. If it's a **Jetty** container, here are the changes:

   ```
   @Bean
   public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory 
       containerFactory(
           @Value("${server.port:8080}") final String port,
           @Value("${jetty.threadPool.maxThreads:600}") final String maxThreads,
           @Value("${jetty.threadPool.minThreads:10}") final String minThreads,
           @Value("${jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout:5000}") final String idleTimeout) {
       final JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =
               new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(Integer.valueOf(port));

       ...
       factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 
            "/error-info.html"));
       ...
       return factory;
   }
   ```
2. If it's a **Tomcat** container, here are the changes:

   ```
   @Bean
   public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer container() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

           @Override
           public void customize(
               ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
               container.addErrorPages(new 
                   ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error-info.html"));

           }
       };
   }
   ```
3. For your `ErrorController`, **don't set view name**. It will pick the view from the error page mapping which was set earlier.

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class ErrorController {

       @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotAccessibleException.class)
       @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
       public ModelAndView handleResourceNotAccessibleException(
           HttpServletRequest req, ResourceNotAccessibleException ex) {
          ...
          ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
          mav.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);

          retrun mav;
       }
    }
   ```
4. Location of **error-info.html** or jsp under `resources/static`

Comment: If you don't want `ErrorInfo`, you can turn it into  a`ModelAndView`. In my case, I use a POJO for my REST services.

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem now is that my  ErrorController it's not taken into account, i am redirected directly to the error page