# How to completely disable spring mvc default error handler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I want to catch and log every exception thrown in my application, so I made:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleDefault(){
```

(yes I will convert it into a problem).

It works, but does not take into account any runtime exception such as NullPointer. So I decided to go further:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleDefault(){
```

But it seems that it is not possible as spring already defines one:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Throwable]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.foo.exception.handlers.MyExceptionHandler.handleDefault(), public default org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.general.ThrowableAdviceTrait.handleThrowable(java.lang.Throwable,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)}

Comment: What is ThrowableAdviceTrait and why do you use it?

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548572/7505731